# Create new array while Iterating over a n dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do I iterate over a numpy array of n dimensions and create a new array of similar shape.

e.g. for the inputs:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3],
                [4,5,6],
                [7,8,9],
                [0,0,0]])
alpha = 3.
median = np.median(arr)
```

I would like to build a new array of same (4,3) with flags set to 1 for a random condition. 
e.g.

```
flag = (arr[i,j] > median - alpha) or (arr[i,j] < median + alpha)
```

I would solve this with 2 for statements

```
flags = arr * 0 
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
         flags[i,j] = (arr[i,j] > median - alpha) or (arr[i,j] < median + alpha)
```

Is there a way to solve this in a simpler and more efficient **pythonic** way ? The solution should ideally also work for n dimensional arrays (1,2, ... n dimensions)

Comment: Umm, right now you're generating `True` flags unless `arr[i,j] == median * alpha`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: True, this is though just an example. What I am asking is the iteration process. I will update the condition to make a bit more sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to iterate at all.

```
np.logical_or(arr < median - alpha, arr > median + alpha)
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is done to avoid loop:

```
alpha = 3.
median = np.median(arr)

abs(arr-median) < alpha

#array([[ True,  True,  True],
#      [ True,  True,  True],
#      [False, False, False],
#      [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

And of course it works for any number of dimensions.

More generally, you can avoid loops each time you can formulate your condition  with [numpy logic functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.logic.html). Python **and** and **or** operator do not map on numpy arrays, and using them implies loop and slow down.

Comment: Sure but your answer is "using" the particular condition that I set. In some cases though this condition may be very complex (or even worse may not be a condition at all) so I was wondering if there is a a more generic solution to avoid these kind of loops.